# Calling child page thumbnail image

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code in my Wordpress site. The shortcode finds the subpages for the current page and returns their title and excerpt. I am trying to integrate the page thumbnail but it is returning the parent page's post thumbnail. Any ideas?

```
  add_shortcode("children-excerpt", "sc_show_children_excerpt");

   function sc_show_children_excerpt($atts, $content = null){
if($atts['length'] > 0 ){
    //maybe set a minimum length here

   }else{
    $atts['length'] = 50;
}


if(isset($atts['id']) && is_numeric($atts['id'])){
    //id specified by shortcode attribute
    $parent_id = $atts['id'];
}else{
    //get the id of the current article that is calling the shortcode
    $parent_id = get_the_ID();
}


$output = "";

$i = 0;

if ( $children = get_children(array(
    'post_parent' => $parent_id,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'page')))
{
    foreach( $children as $child ) {
        $title = $child->post_title;

        $child_excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $child->post_excerpt);

        //split excerpt into array for processing
        $words = explode(' ', $child_excerpt);

        //chop off the excerpt based on the atts->lenth
        $words = array_slice($words, 0, $atts['length']);

        //merge the array of words for the excerpt back into sentances
        $child_excerpt = implode(' ', $words);

        $link = get_permalink($child->ID);

        $test = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' );          
        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);  
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'medium');  
        $image_url = $image_url[0]; 
        $result = '<img src="'.$image_url.'" class="alignleft" />';

        $output .= "<div class='attorney'>";
        $output .= $result;
        $output .= "<a href='$link'>$title</a>";
        $output .= "<p>". $child_excerpt ."</p>";
        $output .= "</div><div class='clear'></div>";
    }
} 

return $output;
```

}

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve better? I think I gathered that you are trying to return thumbnails for all the children of the current post? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct Josh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get your child thumbnails, use this

```
   $image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail($child->ID,'medium'); 
   $result = $image_url;
```

instead of

```
   $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'medium');  
   $image_url = $image_url[0]; 
   $result = '<img src="'.$image_url.'" class="alignleft" />';
```

Comment: David, that did not work. It returned nothing. The original code returns the parent page's featured image and not the featured image on the children pages.

Comment: it worked for me, i tested on my local, are you sure you have the parent child setup correctly?

Comment: Sorry David - you're right! I accidentally kept the get_post_thumbnaiL_id instead of swapping that out for get_the_post_thumbnail.

Thanks SO much!

Comment: David, I noticed you're in Philly - me too! What's your deal? Do you do Wordpress development? I'm always looking for developers to work with!

Comment: yes i do wordpress dev, rails, php, javascript, html5, etc let me know  and yourself?